# About using Python to import Excel data into PPT tables

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-pptx

I want to try to import the data in Excel into the PPT table

The following is my code, but there is an error

```
import pandas as pd
import pptx
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from pptx.util import Pt, Inches, Cm
from pptx.enum.text import PP_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT
from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor

wb = load_workbook('111.xlsx')
ws = wb['sheet2']

df = pd.read_excel('XXX.xlsx', sheet_name=0, usecols='A:P')
df = df.iloc[1:15]
# print(df)
df['Unnamed: 3'] = round(df['Unnamed: 3'].astype('float'), 0)
df['Unnamed: 5'] = df['Unnamed: 5'].apply(lambda x: format(x, '.2%'))


ppt = pptx.Presentation('demo.pptx')
layout = ppt.slide_layouts[12]
slide = ppt.slides.add_slide(layout)

rows = 14
cols = 16

left = top = Cm(2)
width = Cm(6.0)
height = Cm(1.0)

table = slide.shapes.add_table(rows, cols, left, top, width, height).table

for row in range(rows):
    for col in range(cols):
        table.cell(row, col).text = str(df[row][col])

ppt.save("test2.ppt")
```

Error display：

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "……", line 44, in <module>
    table.cell(row, col).text = str(df[row][col])
  File "……", line 3505, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "……", line 3623, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 0
```

I'm a new Python student. If this is an obvious question, don't mind. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

The error is because of `str(df[row][col])`, more specifically `df[row][col]`.
You can't access dataframe elements like this, you must be using iloc. Just change it to `str(df.iloc[row, col])`. This will work.